# Why GTest is converting special character

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using GTest to unit test an older library with MFC classes and having trouble with GTest converting special characters. For example, this test (which fails intentionally) needs to preserve the bullet char

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <afx.h>
namespace UnitTests
{
    TEST(ThisTest, WillFail)
    {
        CString actual = _T("•");
        CString expected = _T("ABC");
        EXPECT_STREQ(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

GTest changed expected to "\xE2\x20AC\xA2".
Visual Studio shows this for the details of expected string:

```
    Name    Value   Type
◢   actual  L"â€¢"  ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>
```

GTest show this for the failed test:

```
    Expected equality of these values:
      expected Which is: L"ABC"
      actual   Which is: L"\xE2\x20AC\xA2"
```

I can’t include MFC as a DLL in GTest and _AFXDLL is defined as a preprocessor allowing #include <afx.h> and CString.

I realize the problem may not be GTest specifically, but something more general in dealing with special characters.

Comment: What happens when you replace `_T("•")` with `_T("\x95")`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MFC, but I [checked your code](https://godbolt.org/z/fWT6aWM8j) using `std::string`. There are two things that might help:

1. You are using [`EXPECT_STREQ`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_STREQ) which should be used for c string (e.g. `char*`) comparison only. I suggest you change it to `EXPECT_EQ` instead. Doing that will give you an output like below, which has the `As Text` format:

```
expected equality of these values:
  expected
    Which is: "ABC"
  actual
    Which is: "\xE2\x80\xA2"
    As Text: "•"
```

2. If you write your own classes, you can [customize how the output is formatted](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values).

Comment: Interesting, I copied your example code which is nearly identical and still get:
Expected equality of these values:
  expected
    Which is: "ABC"
  actual
    Which is: "\xE2\x80\xA2"
    As Text: "â€¢"
```
Any idea what local configuration setting could affect my outcome? I’m running VS 2019.

Comment: Not sure, may be the window that is displaying the output does not support UPF?

Also, I noticed that there is a `--print_utf8` flag which you may want to try adding to your test executable. Are you able to Print that string (may be using cout) in the same terminal and see if it is printed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with encoding. gtest thinks this character has no printable representation, so it falls back into escape sequence.

Had similar problem when writing test which was handling Unicode.

I've solved this by:

- enforcing UTF-8 encoding on all source files
- ensuring that compiler is using UTF-8 when reading sources and placing string literals in final exactable (just add `/utf-8` flag to your build).

If you are building using wide characters this should be enough to make this work. bu I would recommend to configure locale (before gtest init) like this to enforce UTF-8 at run time:

```cpp
void setupGlobalLocale()
{
    const char utf8Name = ".UTF-8";

    // C API should use UTF-8
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, utf8Name);

    // inform standard library application logic uses UTF-8 - literals are encoded in UTF-8
    std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale("C"), utf8Name, std::locale::ctype));
    
    // use current system encoding for printing
    std::locale sysLocale(std::locale(std::locale("C"), "", std::locale::ctype);

    std::cout.imbue(sysLocale);
    std::cerr.imbue(sysLocale);
    std::clog.imbue(sysLocale);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setupGlobalLocale();
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

after this gtest was able to print proper strings and many other things start to work as desired.